# Use JSON Builder with collection

Tags: java, json, groovy

I have this code:

```
    // Write metadate.json
    def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    List myTemplateFilesList = new ArrayList();

    def myTemplate = new MyTemplate(module: ''+module,
            version: ''+version,
            unit: ''+unit,
            defaultPropertiesTargetPath: ''+targetPath)
    myTemplateFilesList.add(myTemplate);
    for (String key : keys) {
        def myTemplateFiles = new MyTemplateFiles(templateName: key,
                templateFileName: key+'.ht',
                targetFileName: key+'{{env}}{{client}}')
        myTemplateFilesList.add(myTemplateFiles);
    }
    jsonBuilder('templateFiles': myTemplateFilesList);
    println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())

class MyTemplate{
    def module
    def version
    def unit
    def defaultPropertiesTargetPath
}

class MyTemplateFiles{
    def templateName
    def templateFileName
    def targetFileName
}
```

***My Output:***

```
{
    "templateFiles": [
        {
            "unit": "WAS-WDI",
            "version": "20_2",
            "defaultPropertiesTargetPath": "defaultPropertiesTargetPath:{{user.home}}/{{component}}/deployments/{{module}}/properties",
            "module":  "wdiCore"
        },
        {
            "templateFileName": "EnvWDI.ht",
            "templateName": "EnvWDI",
            "targetFileName": "EnvWDI{{env}}{{client}}"
        },
        {
            "templateFileName": "WDIHealthCheck.ht",
            "templateName": "WDIHealthCheck",
            "targetFileName": "WDIHealthCheck{{env}}{{client}}"
        },
        {
            "templateFileName": "CachesWDI.ht",
            "templateName": "CachesWDI",
            "targetFileName": "CachesWDI{{env}}{{client}}"
        },
        {
            "templateFileName": ".ht",
            "templateName": "",
            "targetFileName": "{{env}}{{client}}"
        }
    ] }
```

But i want this ***Output***:

```
{
  "module": "wdiCore",
  "version": "20.1.1.0",
  "unit": "WAS-WDI",
  "defaultPropertiesTargetPath":"{{user.home}}/{{component}}/deployments/{{module}}/properties",
  "templateFiles" : 
  [
    { 
      "templateName": "EnvWDI" ,
      "templateFileName": "EnvWDI.ht" , 
      "targetFileName": "EnvWDI{{env}}{{client}}"
    },
    { 
      "templateName": "WDIHealthCheck{env}{client}" ,
      "templateFileName": "WDIHealthCheck.ht" , 
      "targetFileName": "WDIHealthCheck{{env}}{{client}}"
    },
    { 
      "templateName": "CachesWDI" ,
      "templateFileName": "CachesWDI.ht" , 
      "targetFileName": "CachesWDI{{env}}{{client}}",
      "targetPath":"{{user.home}}/{{component}}/properties/cache"
    }
  ]

}
```

What is wrong in my code ..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I have to assume that part of your desired output contains a typo. I expect that the following line:

```
      "templateName": "WDIHealthCheck{env}{client}" ,
```

is actually supposed to be:

```
      "templateName": "WDIHealthCheck" ,
```

Right?

### Solution 1: Define the Groovy objects to reflect the JSON structure

Basically you just need to make your Groovy classes look like the JSON you want to produce. So let's start at the top. You want the top level of your JSON object to contain `module`, `version`, `unit`, `defaultPropertiesTargetPath`, and a list of `templateFiles`. Let's define that structure in Groovy:

```
class MyTemplate{
    def module
    def version
    def unit
    def defaultPropertiesTargetPath
    List templateFiles
}
```

Now, inside that list are more objects, all with roughly the same structure. Let's define THAT structure in Groovy:

```
class MyTemplateFiles {
    def templateName
    def templateFileName
    def targetFileName
}
```

But that is not all, since there is a special case with an additional property:

```
class MySpecialTemplateFiles extends MyTemplateFiles {
    def targetPath
}
```

Then your script code just looks like this (remembering to add the `targetPath` property to the special case):

```
List myTemplateFilesList = new ArrayList()
def myTemplate = new MyTemplate(
        module: module,
        version: version,
        unit: unit,
        defaultPropertiesTargetPath: targetPath)
// add the list to the template, not the other way around
myTemplate.templateFiles = myTemplateFilesList
for (String key : keys) {
    def myTemplateFiles
    // isolates special case
    if (key == "CachesWDI") {
        myTemplateFiles = new MySpecialTemplateFiles(
                templateName: key,
                templateFileName: key+'.ht',
                targetFileName: key+'{{env}}{{client}}',
                targetPath: "{{user.home}}/{{component}}/properties/cache")
    } else {
        myTemplateFiles = new MyTemplateFiles(
                templateName: key,
                templateFileName: key+'.ht',
                targetFileName: key+'{{env}}{{client}}')
    }
    myTemplateFilesList.add(myTemplateFiles)
}
// use template to instantiate jsonBuilder
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(myTemplate)
println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
```

This yields the following output:

```
{
    "unit": "WAS-WDI",
    "version": "20.1.1.0",
    "defaultPropertiesTargetPath": "{{user.home}}/{{component}}/deployments/{{module}}/properties",
    "templateFiles": [
        {
            "templateFileName": "EnvWDI.ht",
            "templateName": "EnvWDI",
            "targetFileName": "EnvWDI{{env}}{{client}}"
        },
        {
            "templateFileName": "WDIHealthCheck.ht",
            "templateName": "WDIHealthCheck",
            "targetFileName": "WDIHealthCheck{{env}}{{client}}"
        },
        {
            "targetPath": "{{user.home}}/{{component}}/properties/cache",
            "templateFileName": "CachesWDI.ht",
            "templateName": "CachesWDI",
            "targetFileName": "CachesWDI{{env}}{{client}}"
        }
    ],
    "module": "wdiCore"
}
```

Properties in JSON objects are unordered, so this is equivalent to your desired output.

### Solution 2: Define the JSON via the JsonBuilder DSL

Dispense with defining classes in Groovy and use the `JsonBuilder` *Domain-Specific Language* (DSL) to define the JSON object directly. In the following I renamed some of your assumed inputs in order to avoid naming conflicts (`module => myModule`, `unit => myUnit`, etc.):

```
def jsonBuilder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
jsonBuilder {
    module myModule
    version myVersion
    unit myUnit
    defaultPropertiesTargetPath myTargetPath
    // the following produces a list of maps for the templateFiles property
    templateFiles keys.collect { key ->
        def map = [
            templateName: key,
            templateFileName: key+'.ht',
            targetFileName: key+'{{env}}{{client}}']
        if (key == "CachesWDI") {
            map.targetPath = "{{user.home}}/{{component}}/properties/cache"
        }
        map
    }
}
println(jsonBuilder.toPrettyString())
```

This program produces the exact output you desire.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is, that all the objects are added to the list.

Try to make an aggregation between MyTemplate and MyTemplateFile.

In other words: 
- MyTemplate should have a list of MyTemplateFile.
- Instead of adding MyTemplateFile to your existing list, add them to the list in MyTemplate
- Only add MyTemplate to the existing list.

regards
slowy